# Java applications for mac

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have never used mac before so I have a question about best way of running java application on mac, since I didn't really find a good answer online.

So I've build a java application and I have to send it to a client that is using mac. I know that you can run `.jar` on mac using `java -jar app.jar` from terminal, but I want a double-clickable icon that a client can only click on and start the program.

I've seen some tutorial where someone has made a `.jar` file that you only double click on and the program starts in macos, so I am not sure if you can run a `.jar` in macos as executable only by double clicking on it?

One other solution that I saw was to make a simple `.command` file that would run the app using `java -jar app.jar`. So I want to know what is the best way of making an executable for mac from a `.jar` file?

Comment: First of all, you need a Java runtime installed on that system. That is the first thing to worry about. The rest of your question isn't clear. When you got a tutorial (and I guess there are plenty)... Have you tried all its steps?

Comment: @GhostCat
I didn't try to implement anything yet, I want to see my options first. I just got confused about the guy double clicking on a jar and starting a program, so I wanted to know if you can run all jar files in mac as executables..

Answer (score 1):

Yours isn't a *bad* question.

The answer is "it depends".  It's entirely possible the "best solution" is to simply send the .jar file with instructions for invoking it.

Please look at the Oracle documentation:

> [Java Documentation Section 7: Self-Contained Application
>   Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI)
>
> **7.1 Introduction**
>
> The Java packaging tools provide built-in support for several formats
>   of self-contained application packages. The basic package is a single
>   folder on your hard drive that includes all application resources and
>   the JRE. The package can be redistributed as is, or you can build an
>   installable package (for example, EXE or DMG format.)
>
> From the standpoint of process, producing a self-contained application
>   package is similar to producing a basic application package as
>   discussed in Chapter 5, "Packaging Basics," with the following
>   differences:
>
> *Self-contained application packages must be explicitly requested by passing additional arguments to the  Ant task or
>   javapackager tool.*
>
> *Operating system and tool requirements must be met to be able to build a package in a specific format.*
>
> *Self-contained application packages can only be built using JDK 7 Update 6 or later.*
>
> While it is easy to create a basic self-contained application package,
>   tailoring it to achieve the best user experience for a particular
>   distribution method usually requires some effort and a deeper
>   understanding of the topic.
>
> ...
>
> **7.3.5.1 OS X**
>
> The resulting package on OS X is an "application bundle".
>
> Several configuration parameters are placed in the Info.plist file in
>   the application bundle and must conform to the following rules:
>
> > Application ID (or main class name if ID is not specified) is used as CFBundleIdentifier.
> >
> > Application version is used as CFBundleShortVersionString.
>
> OS X 10.8 introduces Gatekeeper, which prevents execution of untrusted
>   code by default, regardless of whether this code is implemented in
>   Objective-C or Java.
>
> The user can manually enable the application to run, but this is not a
>   perfect user experience. To get optimal user experience, obtain a
>   Developer ID Certificate from Apple. The Mac bundler uses the
>   certificate to sign the .app folder. If your local user information
>   differs from the name of the certificate, you might need to set the
>   bundle argument mac.signing-key-user-name, as shown in the following
>   example: